# Thank you, Jarrod Dixon

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, thanks

[Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon), [Stack Overflow Valued Associate #00002](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00002/), [announced yesterday](https://twitter.com/jarrod_dixon/status/1430922065436192771) that he is no longer working at Stack Overflow:

> **@jarrod_dixon**: After over 13 years at @StackOverflow, today is my last day :(
>
> It has been an honor and a privilege to serve the best community out there - thank you to everyone that makes Stack such an amazing resource for developers <3 <3 <3

Without Jarrod, Stack Overflow would literally not exist in the way it does today. There isn't really a way to quantify 13 years of development work, but the accumulated time and effort that he has put into this site is an *enormous* amount.

So thank you, Jarrod, and good luck in your future endeavours! You'll be missed.

Comment: Now we get to blame everything that breaks on him now that he's not here to defend himself.

Comment: Adam Lear is also leaving or has left or will come back next year. Not sure which. Saw this piece of news on  their Twitter account.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - He's simply on vacation / sabbatical :) He was doing a bit of trolling.

Answer (score 9):

Jarrod,

I didn't really know you.  But I know of you, and of what you've done for Stack Exchange, and I'm one of quite a few who admires the effort and work you put in for us.  So long and thanks for all the fish - may your waffles be perfectly cooked!

Answer (score 8):

Man, while I realise that 13 years is practically a lifetime in the tech industry, it's bittersweet to see the giants upon whose shoulders we've stood leave for new adventures.

Good luck wherever you go, and may you never be poked by sharp sticks.